# How can I broadcast message to all sockets?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-websocket, stomp, stomp-websocket

I have a messaging app and I am using `stomp-websocket` with spring.

I am sending message to sockets like:

```
messageBean.convertAndSend( "/topic/message.${USER_ID}",  ${Message_Object} )
```

However, for some cases I want to send message to whole users that actively have socket.

I mean, I want to send message like:

```
messageBean.convertAndSend( "/topic/message",  ${Message_Object} )
```

I mean I don't want to create new socket for this messages. The front end application which is using this socket like `sockJs.subscribe("/topic/message.${userId}")` I dont want to broke that logic.

How can I send the message like I said, or how can I achive this logic?

Thanks for helps.

Comment: You can get all the user active sessions iterate and send the message right ?

Comment: Yeah, I did the solution like that but little different, I wrote a listener class and listened all subscription events of sockets that i want to listen and then i stored that list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure really sure if this answers your question, but methods that are annotated with `@SendTo` and `@MessageMapping` will automatically broadcast return value to all subscribers.

In case it might help you, here is an implementation of a [Kalah game](https://github.com/seifeddinedridi/Kalah) I wrote which uses Spring WebSocket to broadcast game status to active players in real time.

Comment: oh okey firstly thank you for your answer, I reviewed your codes that you have mentioned but I have actually websockets for every user like : `/topic/message.${userId}` and I need something like getting all sockets then parsing them and getting userIds, aftwerwards.